# how to convert url parameter to normal url

Tags: php

My website is coded in php, its using url parameters for different pages for ex.

```
http://www.studplex.com/school-details/?user_id=137
```

so i want to change it in to normal url just like in this format

```
http://www.studplex.com/school-details/bachpan-a-play-school
```

is it possible to do so now. i am newbie so please help, And does this help me in SEO

Comment: You need to look for `url rewriting`. An exact answer would depend on the type of server you use and the database structure.

Comment: As this is a Wordpress website, you could just use: Options -> Permalinks.
Or install one of a bunch of plugins available...

Comment: you can save user_id in a session , for pages and other data you can use url rewriting. A framework choice is best for security/clean url issues

Comment: @Wils firstly thanks for the reply, do you know any plugin that can help me without problems

Comment: @AnkitJain There are some available, here you are a couple: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-url/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-clean-url-seo/ also this article here have a very good explanation and some other plugins to help you: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation on how to do it with Apache or if you prefer, directly in plain php.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: Acutally the problem is http://www.studplex.com/school-details/ this is a page and we are getting the data by passing this parameter http://www.studplex.com/school-details/?user_id=137. so still is it possible to rewrite or there will be some problems

Comment: You could rewrite it to /school-details/user/137